# Cannot mount hard-drive at one specific path

Tags: filesystems, usb-drive

I have a generic 8Tb external HDD that I'd like to mount to `/lovelace`. This has worked in the past, but often when I restart the machine, it does not automatically remount, and then I have no end of problems getting it remounted. Some possibly relevant info:

- The drive lives at `/dev/sda2`
- I have a vague memory that one time I was trying to figure this out using the gui, I cycled through my drives and found some other one was being automatically mounted there.

So, I've tried

```
$ sudo mount /dev/sda2 /lovelace
$ ls /lovelace # there should be a number of directories
$ sudo umount /lovelace
umount: /lovelace: not mounted
$ sudo rmdir /lovelace; sudo mkdir /lovelace; sudo mount /dev/sda2 /lovelace
$ ls /lovelace
$
```

So here's the weird thing - I can mount the drive basically anywhere else

```
$ sudo mount /dev/sda2 /media/drive
$ ls /media/drive
echo  genomes  humann2_databases  lost+found  students
```

I can even mount it at `/Lovelace` (with a capital `L`), but no matter what I try, I can't mount it at `/lovelace`. What can I do to debug this?

```
❯ df -aTh
Filesystem     Type         Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
sysfs          sysfs           0     0     0    - /sys
proc           proc            0     0     0    - /proc
udev           devtmpfs      32G     0   32G   0% /dev
devpts         devpts          0     0     0    - /dev/pts
tmpfs          tmpfs        6.3G  1.9M  6.3G   1% /run
/dev/nvme0n1p3 ext4         220G  133G   77G  64% /
securityfs     securityfs      0     0     0    - /sys/kernel/security
tmpfs          tmpfs         32G     0   32G   0% /dev/shm
tmpfs          tmpfs        5.0M     0  5.0M   0% /run/lock
tmpfs          tmpfs         32G     0   32G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
cgroup2        cgroup2         0     0     0    - /sys/fs/cgroup/unified
cgroup         cgroup          0     0     0    - /sys/fs/cgroup/systemd
pstore         pstore          0     0     0    - /sys/fs/pstore
efivarfs       efivarfs        0     0     0    - /sys/firmware/efi/efivars
none           bpf             0     0     0    - /sys/fs/bpf
cgroup         cgroup          0     0     0    - /sys/fs/cgroup/devices
cgroup         cgroup          0     0     0    - /sys/fs/cgroup/net_cls,net_prio
cgroup         cgroup          0     0     0    - /sys/fs/cgroup/cpu,cpuacct
cgroup         cgroup          0     0     0    - /sys/fs/cgroup/perf_event
cgroup         cgroup          0     0     0    - /sys/fs/cgroup/memory
cgroup         cgroup          0     0     0    - /sys/fs/cgroup/blkio
cgroup         cgroup          0     0     0    - /sys/fs/cgroup/hugetlb
cgroup         cgroup          0     0     0    - /sys/fs/cgroup/cpuset
cgroup         cgroup          0     0     0    - /sys/fs/cgroup/pids
cgroup         cgroup          0     0     0    - /sys/fs/cgroup/rdma
cgroup         cgroup          0     0     0    - /sys/fs/cgroup/freezer
systemd-1      -               -     -     -    - /proc/sys/fs/binfmt_misc
hugetlbfs      hugetlbfs       0     0     0    - /dev/hugepages
mqueue         mqueue          0     0     0    - /dev/mqueue
debugfs        debugfs         0     0     0    - /sys/kernel/debug
tracefs        tracefs         0     0     0    - /sys/kernel/tracing
fusectl        fusectl         0     0     0    - /sys/fs/fuse/connections
configfs       configfs        0     0     0    - /sys/kernel/config
/dev/loop1     squashfs      56M   56M     0 100% /snap/core18/1944
/dev/loop3     squashfs      62M   62M     0 100% /snap/emote/9
/dev/loop2     squashfs      62M   62M     0 100% /snap/emote/11
/dev/loop4     squashfs      65M   65M     0 100% /snap/gtk-common-themes/1513
/dev/loop0     squashfs      56M   56M     0 100% /snap/core18/1932
/dev/loop5     squashfs      32M   32M     0 100% /snap/snapd/10492
/dev/nvme0n1p2 vfat         4.0G  2.1G  2.0G  52% /recovery
/dev/nvme0n1p1 vfat         498M  308M  190M  62% /boot/efi
/dev/loop6     squashfs     163M  163M     0 100% /snap/gnome-3-28-1804/145
/dev/loop7     squashfs      32M   32M     0 100% /snap/snapd/10707
/dev/loop8     squashfs      65M   65M     0 100% /snap/gtk-common-themes/1514
tmpfs          tmpfs        6.3G   20K  6.3G   1% /run/user/120
gvfsd-fuse     -               -     -     -    - /run/user/120/gvfs
binfmt_misc    binfmt_misc     0     0     0    - /proc/sys/fs/binfmt_misc
/dev/sdb1      ext4         1.9T  262G  1.5T  15% /babbage
/dev/sda2      ext4         7.3T  6.3T  645G  91% /media/drive
/dev/sda2      ext4         7.3T  6.3T  645G  91% /Lovelace
```

Comment: You've got `/dev/sda2` mounted on `/Lovelace` but your example's referring to `/lovelace`. Three questions (a) are you definitely getting the case correct (capital `L` vs lowercase `l`)? (b) given that `/dev/sdb1` is mounted on `/babbage` is the problematic partition in question really `/dev/sdb2`? (c) Do you have the shell option (or filesystem option) set that tells it to ignore case sensitivity in filenames (so that `/lovelace` could conceivably be the same as `/Lovelace`)?

Comment: (a) Yes, as I mentioned in the post, I'm able to mount of I do it to `/Lovelace`, but not if I do `/lovelace`. The results from df are after doing those two commands at the end (b) those were typos - those should all have been sda2 (I've now fixed it). `/babbage` is a completely different drive (an SSD), and there is no sdb2 (c) no - at least I don't think so. If I do `ls /lovelace` there's either nothing there or it says directory not found, while `ls /Lovelace` shows the drive contents

Comment: 1. You've got `sda2` listed in the set of mountpoints twice. 2. Is the backtick at the end of the very first line of code iust a typo in your question? 3. Are there directories in /media/drive _before_ you try to mount `sda2`? 4. Do you have evidence that there really is data on `sda2`?

Comment: What is return code of the `mount` command with `/lovelace` (just run `echo $?` after running the `mount` command)? Can you run it again with `LIBMOUNT_DEBUG=all` set (e.g. `sudo LIBMOUNT_DEBUG=all mount /dev/sda2 /lovelace`) and post the output here (or on pastebin, it might be quite long).

Comment: 1. Right. I can mount it seemingly any number of times (I haven't tried more than 2), at any location other than `/lovelace`. That said, the issue was first noticed when it's not mounted at all, and persists after unmounting from everywhere. 2. Yes, thanks - fixed now 3. No. The directory `/media/drive` itself (or any other place I mount to) has to exist, but there's nothing else there. 4. Yes, mounting it anywhere else, I can see all the directories, use files etc. Plus, as I said, before restarting the computer, it *was* mounted at `/lovelace` (lowercase) and was working fine

Comment: Did you try the lazy mount? umount -l and mount -l

Comment: Didn't know that was a thing, but just tried it and I see the same behavior - no error, but it won't mount to `/lovelace`, but will mount in other places

Comment: @VojtechTrefny return code 0, output from second command: https://gist.github.com/kescobo/ed52bc759a185d9be3a2f5e4609790d3

Comment: @VojtechTrefny for completeness, I just added the same output for mounting to `/Lovelace` (which works) as well, I don't know how to pip those outputs to files in order to diff them, but scanning through by eye I can't spot any difference